# Schema Directives don't execute in LTR order specified in schema

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server, graphql-tools

I am using `graphql-tools@v6` and I have implemented two directives `@map` and `@filter`. My goal is to use them like a map and filter pipeline. In some cases, I want to map before filtering and in other cases, vice-versa. The directives are implemented using the [Schema Directives API](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/schema-directives#what-about-directiveresolvers) and they work as expected when only one directive is applied.

However, if I use them together, then they always execute in one specific order which doesn't match how they are declared in the schema.

For example

```
directive @map on FIELD_DEFINITION
directive @filter on FIELD_DEFINITION

# usage
type MyType {
    list1: [String!]! @map @filter
    list2: [String!]! @filter @map
}
```

In this case, either both fields are mapped and then filtered or vice-versa. The order is controlled by how I pass them in `schemaTransforms` property.

```
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  schemaTransforms: [mapDirective, filterDirective] # vs [filterDirective, mapDirective]
});
```

I believe since these transforms are passed as an array, so their order of execution depends on the ordering of array. I can replace them with `directiveResolvers` but they are limited in what they can do.

But what throws me off is the following statement from the documentation

> Existing code that uses directiveResolvers could consider migrating to direct usage of mapSchema

Because they have different behavior when it comes to order of execution, I don't see how they are interchangeable.

Can someone explain if there is a way to guarantee that the Schema Directives execute in the order they are used in the schema for a particular field?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this github issue for in depth discussion](https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/issues/1606).

The new API doesn't work the same way as `directiveResolvers` or `schemaDirectives`. A `schemaTransform` is applied to the entire schema before the next one contrary to the other two in which the all the transforms are applied to a particular field before visiting the next field node. There are two approaches to this in my opinion:

1. Create a new `@pipeline` directive which takes a list of names of other directives and then applies them in the order like `directiveResolvers`.
2. I took a bit different route where I created a new function `attachSchemaTransforms` just like `attachDirectiveResolvers` which visits each node and applies all the directives in order.

```
export function attachSchemaTransforms(
  schema: GraphQLSchema,
  schemaTransforms: Record<string, FieldDirectiveConfig>, // a custom config object which contains the transform and the directive name
): GraphQLSchema {
  if (typeof schemaTransforms !== 'object') {
    throw new Error(`Expected schemaTransforms to be of type object, got ${typeof schemaTransforms}`);
  }

  if (Array.isArray(schemaTransforms)) {
    throw new Error('Expected schemaTransforms to be of type object, got Array');
  }

  return mapSchema(schema, {
    [MapperKind.OBJECT_FIELD]: oldFieldConfig => {
      const fieldConfig = { ...oldFieldConfig };

      const directives = getDirectives(schema, fieldConfig);

      Object.keys(directives).forEach(directiveName => {
        const config = schemaTransforms[directiveName];
        if (config) {
          const { apply, name } = config;
          const directives = getDirectives(schema, fieldConfig);
          if (directives[name]) {
            const directiveArgs: unknown = directives[name]
            apply(fieldConfig, directiveArgs);
            return fieldConfig;
          }
        }
      });

      return fieldConfig;
    },
  });
}
```